# How do you change image in all uitableview cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a play icon in each cell. When you tap on that play icon it changes to a "Pause" icon. That works marvellously, but if you tap on an icon in another cell, how do I notify the previous cell to change back into a "play" icon? Basically I think I need a way to notify all the UIImage views inside cells at once. All of them for the whole table

Comment: Put all your information in a data model. When you load the table, the cells should reflect the data model. When you click a cell, update the model and reload the affected cell by reloading its indexPath. If an action on a cell affects more than the individual cell, reload the affected section or whole table. You have to do this because only the cells on screen exist. When you scroll off they are reused for cells scrolling on.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a var for playing indexPath.

When tap on another cell:

For visible cell: checking in array of visible cells with playing indexPath. -> if indexPath is in visible cell change 'pause' to 'play'
Then -> assign playing indexPath to current cell.

For unloaded cell: check it in cellForRowAtIndex. if indexPath != playingIndexPath -> 'play'

Sorry, I can't write ios code because you didn't show any. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Three simple steps which you need to do in the sequence

1.In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: datasource method, set the default image of the imageView as 'play'.

2.When the imageView of any cell is tapped, call the tableView reloadData method, which will reload the imageView of all cells to the default image.

3.Now change the imageView of the tapped cell to 'pause'.

As the second step sets the imageView of other cells to default, no separate notification is required. Happy coding :)